# numpy fast operation for slicing specific cells from a nd array

Tags: python, numpy

After profiling the following `load data` function, I've realized the following lines are a major bottleneck:

```
 dist_1 = dist[random_labels, :][:, random_labels]  
 dist_2 = dist[other_random_labels, :][:, other_random_labels]
```

where the size of `dist` is `6000,6000` and the random labels is of length `5000`.
I'm trying to use `np.take` but

```
np.take(dist_1,[random_labels,random_labels]) == dist_1[random_labels, :][:, random_labels]
```

is `False`.
where the dimention of `np.take(dist_1,[random_labels,random_labels])` is `(2,5000)`
Is there an efficient way of doing this in numpy?

edit: this is the closest I've got:

```
 dist_1 = np.take(np.take(dist, random_labels, axis=0), random_labels, axis=1)
```

Comment: using np._ix produces "memory error"

Comment: Does - `np.ix_(random_labels,random_labels)` produce memory error or `dist[np.ix_(random_labels,random_labels)]`?

Comment: np.ix_(random_labels,random_labels)

Comment: Try : `dist[random_labels[:,None],random_labels]`.

Comment: Well, it's not faster than np.take(np.take(dist, random_labels, axis=0), random_labels, axis=1)

Comment: Yeah with selecting 5000 out of 6000 isn't helping with np.ix_. Reopened.

Comment: Also, would `random_labels` be sorted?

Comment: no, it's also a permutation